# How can I infer an object property's value in TypeScript when using mapped types?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to create a singleton `factoryLookup` in typescript that enforces that I have a factory defined for every value in a union type (i.e. a mapped lookup type), however I also want to be able to infer the signature (could be a value or function of arbitrary arguments) for any value that is looked up. Here is a code sample:

```
// Using a simple object, I can create a map between a key and an arbitrary function or value
const factoryLookup = {
  foo: (message: string, count: number): string => message + count,
  bar: (): number => 1,
};

// TypeScript can infer function signature of the foo and bar values
factoryLookup.foo('hello world', 3); // foo's signature: (message: string, count: number) => string
factoryLookup.bar(); // bar's signature: () => number

type FactoryTypes = 'foo' | 'bar' | 'baz';

// With a mapped type, TypeScript can enforce I have *something* defined for every member I am mapping
const typedFactoryLookup: { [key in FactoryTypes]: any } = {
  foo: (message: string, count: number) => {},
  bar: () => {},
  baz: (obj: any) => {},
};

// However, I don't know how to infer the mapped values
typedFactoryLookup.foo; // any type
typedFactoryLookup.bar; // any type
typedFactoryLookup.baz; // any type
```

***I want the type safety of ensuring I have a function defined for every value in my union/enum type, but also the type inference to know what the signature of that value is.***

Any ideas on how to solve this, or alternative approaches that achieve the same goals would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you explicitly type a variable, that will be its type no inference will occur. You can get the behavior you want, but you need to use the inference behavior of functions.

```
type FactoryTypes = 'foo' | 'bar' | 'baz';


function createTypedFactoryLookup<T extends { [key in FactoryTypes]: any }>(factory: T) {
    return factory;
}
const typedFactoryLookup = createTypedFactoryLookup({
    foo: (message: string, count: number) => {},
    bar: () => {},
    baz: (obj: any) => {},
})

typedFactoryLookup.foo; // (message: string, count: number) => void
typedFactoryLookup.bar; // () => void
typedFactoryLookup.baz; // (obj: any) => void
```

You can also create a version that takes in the type for the keys, but you will need to use a function that returns a function as typescript does not support specifying only some type parameters (it might be supported in 3.1)

```
function createTypedFactoryLookup<TKeys extends string>(){
    return function <T extends { [key in TKeys]: any }>(factory: T) {
        return factory;
    }
}
const typedFactoryLookup = createTypedFactoryLookup<FactoryTypes>()({
    foo: (message: string, count: number) => {},
    bar: () => {},
    baz: (obj: any) => {},
})
```